# Different way to write getter and setter

Tags: getter, setter

Hi i have code that shows an error "Error: simplegetset Compile Error: Variable is not visible: userinput at line 14 column 15".I just want to know is this not right way to define get and set here is the code.

```
public class simplegetset
{
  // public String userinput{get; set;}
   public string userinput{set;}
   //public string userinput{get;}
  /* public void setUserinput(string userinput)
   {
       this.userinput = userinput;
   } */


  public void getUserinput()
   {
       return userinput;
   } 
}
```

And same if I declare getter setter like this and when I write like this

```
public class simplegetset {  
    public string userinput{get;}                                                                                                                                                 public string userinput{get;}
    public void setUserinput(string userinput){
       this.userinput = userinput;
    } 
}
```

Its shown an same error "Variable is not visible" is this not right way to declare getter and setter?

Comment: They're both right technically, but as Caspar pointed out you have a syntax error in your getter method (void return on a getter doesn't make sense).  I avoid mixing the two types though.  There is also a longer form of the get; set; that allows for processing (e.g.:  get { // code here and return statement })

Comment: Take a look at the [Apex Properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) documentation for examples of the get/set syntax that is shorthand for writing getter and setter methods.

Comment: I added another example below. Like Keith C said, read the docs - it's pretty clear.

Comment: Actually, the problem you are really having is that you are **MIXING** the two types of getters/setters - either use the `{get;set;}` syntax or use the `getVarName` syntax - not a bit of both.

Comment: Its mean its not good way to declare getter setter either you declare in single line like this "public String userinput{get; set;}" or by defining seprate both getter and setter "public void setUserinput(string userinput){ }" and like "public String getUserinput()" this pattern

Comment: You can use either, but not both and not a mix of both.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine your getter like this:

```
public String getUserinput()
{
   return userinput;
}
```

You are not returning a string from the getter,  currently you are returning void, which won't work for a getter.

Another example:

```
  public String userinput {
  get {
      return this.userinput;
  }
  set {
      this.userinput = value;
  }
```

Note, `value` is predefined and you need to use this name.

Comment: Hi casper i redefine using string return type but its shows same error Variable is not visible: userinput at line 14 column 15

Comment: hi casper what if i want to pass value from vf page beacuse i used vf page for this controller

Comment: The page and controller will handle it for you. All you really need is this: `public String userinput {get;set;}` - this is because you are not doing anything else in the getters/setters and can use the default.

Comment: Thanks Casper i firstly tried same stament but i learn to use getter and setter in different  ways and now i know there is only two right way. first with single statement as you define above and second right getter and setter seprately Thanks.

Comment: Oh so you already knew how to use! I see know. Yep, I think there are only two ways :)